# Script tab in firebug equivalent for chrome

Tags: google-chrome, firebug, google-chrome-devtools

I'd like to be able to set break points on `JS` in individual files. I can do this to inline script in `chrome` with sources tab. This is isn't very helpful as I have almost no inline `JS`.

In firebug you have the script tab, in which you can select from all the `js` files on the site.

Where is Chrome's version of the Script tab in Firebug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear what is the problem.
Chrome has DeveloperTools. It can be invoked with help of Ctrl+I (Cmd+I on Mac) shortcut or though menu.

In the DevTools window there is Sources tab that can show you the js files of the site.
You can use Ctrl+O shortcut for opening a particular file.

[image]

Or you can use sources tree pane.

[image]

If the source file is obfuscated/minified then you could pretty print it with help of a button in the status bar with curly bracers. Also DevTools supports source maps. You can set a breakpoint in the js file and do number of other things typical for an IDE.

Comment: you say its not clear, but i think the UI sucks on chrome for this particular feature. Its not clear, so thank you for pointing out this tiny odd backwards play button.